# Memory leak using startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-activity

If I start activity B from A using startActivityForResult, A seems to be kind of "listening" to B's response. In which case it won't be garbage collected if I somehow manage to migrate from B to C and don't finish B.

Is this a memory leak ? If I startActivityForResult, do I HAVE to force the user to return to the caller activity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startActivityForResult` just tells the Android OS to call `onActivityResult` in activity A once B has closed. Activity A isn't actively 'listening' for anything.

If C is completely unrelated to A and B you could set the activity result as cancelled, finish the activity and launch C. However just keeping them in the back stack whilst the user works with activity C is fine too.

You can find out more in the [docs.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)